# Traversal Flow Control in Arangodb 3.0+

Tags: arangodb, aql

I am looking for a way to control the traversal flow in ArangoDB 3.0+ the same way we could do it with a filter functions through the TRAVERSAL in ArangoDB 2 to prevent unnecessary vertices exploration. Is there an alternative or is it still possible to use the visitors/filters functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into the migration docs from 2.x to 3.x [here](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/cookbook/AQL/MigratingEdgeFunctionsTo3.html#traversal-and-traversaltree) and also in the current AQL traversal docs [here](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.1/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html). The docs should answer all your questions.

Comment: I already did, but it does not. It shows how to filter the results but not how to control exploration flow. If you see something that I did not see, please let me know.